# Bibliography Customisation for Overleaf

Tags: latex, overleaf

I currently have this code:

```
 \usepackage[
backend=biber,
citestyle=authoryear,
bibstyle=authoryear,
maxcitenames=2,
maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{reference.bib}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\setlength\bibitemsep{1em}
```

Which prints the bibliography like this:

> Birrell, S. and Donnelley, P. (2004). “Erving Goffman’s Influence on
> the Sociology ofSport”. In: ed. by R. Giulianotti. Sport and Modern
> Social Theorists. London: Pal-grave Macmillian UK, pp. 49–64.

This is the info from the .bib file:

```
@inbook{birrel:2004,
author={S. Birrell and P. Donnelley},
editor={Giulianotti,R.},
year={2004},
title={Erving Goffman's Influence on the Sociology of Sport},
series={Sport and Modern Social Theorists},
publisher={Palgrave Macmillian UK},
address={London},
pages={49-64}
```

}

I need to remove the parentheses from around the year to conform to Leeds Harvard style, which is like this:

> Family name, INITIAL(S). Year. Title of article. Journal Title. Volume(issue number), page numbers.

Help!

Comment: Can you make a compilable [mre]?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - this is the code which styles my references and bibliography. I'm trying to keep everything else the same but remove the brackets from around the year in the bibliography, does this help?

Comment: Can you please make a short but compilable document with all the boring stuff like a documentclass etc.